# add a class to specific element by javascript and not repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is sample code explain what i want:

```
<div id="someId">
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="targetClass"></div>
</div>
<div id="someId">
<div class="someClass"></div>
<div class="targetClass"></div>
</div>
<div id="someId">
<div class="someClass"></div>
</div>
```

this code for `jquery`:

```
var $newDiv = $("<div/>")
.addClass("targetClass")
$(".someClass").append($newDiv);
```

result is add a TargetClass in `div` number 3 and repeat same class in first and second `div`.

question is how i add class in the last `div` and not repeat it in another `div`.

Comment: ID of an element must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your code, you want new div as a sibling of your `.someClass` div rather than its child.

Simply replace this line

```
 $(".someClass").append($newDiv);
```

by

```
 $( "div[id]:not(:has(.targetClass))" ).append($newDiv); //will append new div to all those divs which doesn't have child element with targetclass

var $newDiv = $("<div/>").addClass("targetClass");
$( "div[id]:not(:has(.targetClass))" ).append($newDiv);
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q5p8y7qg/)

Comment: @mag I am assuming that `someId` is just a placeholder here and it is going to be unique in your actual context.

Comment: if i have a more of class not one class what i do ?

Comment: @MAG you mean more classes which doesn't have targetClass?

Comment: thank you for helping but not working no appear effect

Comment: @MAG you will only see the effect if the element has some values https://jsfiddle.net/q5p8y7qg/1/

Comment: @MAG yes, you just need to give the selector for the div you want to choose

Comment: i can't make it can you help me
Edit: Thanks I make it

Answer (score 0):

Using .last() will select the last element you are searching for.

```
jQuery(".someClass").last().append($newDiv);
```

Comment: if i have a more of class not one class what i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have unique IDs for parent divs as *someId* is not valid if it is the actual ID applied on multiple elements, this makes the markup invalid.

Use `.last().parent()` to put the element as a sibling element as they share same parent:

```js
var $newDiv = $("<div/>")
  .addClass("targetClass").html('dynamic target element.')

$(".someClass").last().parent().append($newDiv);
```

```css
div{border:solid 1px red; margin:10px 0 0 0;}
div div{border:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someId-1">
  <div class="someClass">some</div>
  <div class="targetClass">target</div>
</div>
<div id="someId-2">
  <div class="someClass">some</div>
  <div class="targetClass">target</div>
</div>
<div id="someId-3">
  <div class="someClass">here after this elem should add</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i have a more of class not one class what i do ?

Comment: What? didn't get you. Can you come again plz?

Comment: @MAG check the snippet added.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to add div with `targetClass` to a div with `someId` if it donot exists, you can use the `find()` function:

```
if($('#someId').find('.someClass').length == 0) {
   var $newDiv = $("<div/>")
    .addClass("targetClass")
    $("#someId").append($newDiv);
}
```